# internet explorer 11 rgba refuses to work

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using IE 11 and it refuses to make rgba work on my page, while rgba works on some web sites, i can't understand why

My page: note the rgba underlined with **red**
[image: My page]

some internet page: rgba works ok

[image]

Comment: What's the rendering mode?

Comment: don't know, standart i guess

Comment: Can we see the input? I'm thinking it might be something like the order of declaration.

Comment: You can find out what rendering mode IE is in by going to the [emulation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/847OX.png) tab in the debugging tools.

Comment: ok, so it apparently is using IE7 as default rendering..., using  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" > at the top of the <head> fixes it :)

Comment: what if you use the #ARGB format instead of rgba() - the color should be #99F95F5F

Answer (score 15, accepted):

apparently IE11 was using IE7 mode as default rendering

using

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

fixes it :)

Comment: This also fixed my problems with border radius, box shadow and text shadow.

Comment: by adding this tag, will it still work for older versions or IE or does it only work with Edge?