# Internet explorer showing different color font than it's computed color in dev tools

Tags: html, css, colors

In IE11, I have a font that is blue, but I want it to be red. I styled it, and checked in dev tools and it shows it's computed color to be red, but it is still blue on the page.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

If I open it in chrome, it is red.

Thanks

The text is the `show users` on the left side. Right side shows the dev tools computed values. It shows red as computed.

[image]

Comment: Post an [mcve] please

Comment: Have you tried forcing IE11 to use different rendering engine? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867656/internet-explorer-11-rgba-refuses-to-work

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are working within SharePoint? There might be another CSS rule as part of the SP template that is crushing your rule. It might be an IE-only thing that Chrome ignores, explaining why it works the way you expect in Chrome but not in IE.