# Angular 4.x - CSS Background color not changing IE11

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer-11, background-color

I have some code within an Angular 4.x application that works fine in Chrome/Firefox but does nothing within Internet Explorer 11 - a user clicks a div which changes the css background colour of the div.header (no issues in modern browsers) but within IE11 - can anyone suggest why this is?

```
<div class="header" [style.background-color]="note ? colours[note.colour] : selectedColor">

<div (click)="selectColor('#3b589799', 'blue')" class="select opt --blue"></div>
<div (click)="selectColor('#bf3a2b99', 'red')" class="select opt --red"></div>
<div (click)="selectColor('#4cae4f99', 'green')" class="select opt --green"></div>
```

// js controller

```
selectColor(color, choice): void {
    this.selectedColor = color;
    this.selected = choice;
}
```

Comment: I think this is because those are RGBA colors, and [IE 11 does not support rgba](https://caniuse.com/#search=rgba). Perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22964400/3055401) might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div (click)="selectColor('rgba(59, 88, 151, 0.6)')" class="select opt --blue">b</div>
    <div (click)="selectColor('rgba(191, 58, 43, 0.6)')" class="select opt --red">r</div>
    <div (click)="selectColor('rgba(76, 174, 79, 0.6)')" class="select opt --green">g</div>
```

use rgba as i am using. it works.

Comment: thanks @Danish - got confused as rgba appears to not be supported in IE11 according to caniuse.com... but strangely it works?? :confused-face thanks again